# On iPad, video doesn't go fullscreen using HTML5

Tags: ipad, html, mobile-safari

I tried getting a video to display fullscreen on iPad using HTML5, but the result I get is:

1. First time click video is play
2. Second time click fullscreen video is play it will appear.

I can't get both the video to play and turn fullscreen when activated.

Here's the source I've been using:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#te").bind('click', function() { 
        $('#myVideoTag')[0].play(); 
        $('#myVideoTag')[0].webkitEnterFullScreen(); 
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the same issue, and setTimeout seems to be the best solution I've run into.

This is what is working for me:

note: the videoEnable function is called through an onclick attribute in the "a" tag

```
//define function

var videoEnable = function(videoCount) {

    //Play video
    $('video').get(videoCount).play(); 

    //Timeout before fullscreen registers
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('video').get(videoCount).webkitEnterFullscreen();
    }, 2000);
}
```

Is that what you are looking for?