# Html5 video tag is not working on iPad

Tags: iphone, html, ipad, cordova

Using `PhoneGap`, I'm trying to display videos on a page.

All video tags are showing the *play* icon, but when I click on it, it does not play the video. This issue shows up only on iPad, not on iPhone.

Here's the markup I'm using:

```
<video id="video1" width="100" height="100" controls>
    <source src="video1.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
</video>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can also recommend Projekktor jquery plugin. 
check it at: http://www.projekktor.com/

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using `JavaScript` to enable the videos to run fullscreen.
It now runs fine on iPad and iPhone, here's a link to a question [that helped me figure it out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10595839/fullscreen-video-not-working-ipad).

Comment: you may be able to replace the timeout by listening for the 'playing' event.